# How to stop a rogue print job?

Tags: printing

We have an HP LaserJet P2050 here at the office connected directly to the LAN. One of the machines is printing tons of pages onto it. The problem is we can't find which machine is doing that. The printing continues even after turning off the printer and turning it on again. Is there a way to view the print queue on the printer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried opening a web browser to the IP address of the printer? Most network printers have a web interface and should have job listings.

Answer (score 1):

https://[ip of printer]

if you don't know the ip of the printer, check out:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=3662052&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3662052&objectID=c01594549

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but the printer should support syslog logging, which would hopefully tell you which machine is printing.